# C# VS 2010 reports error while editing but it compiles and runs successfully

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, optional-parameters

I have optional parameters generated by CodeDom. For example:

```
class Square
{
    public Square([Optional()] int side) { }
}
```

I have a call statement:

```
Square sq = new Square();
```

While I'm editing, my Error List window shows:
    'Square' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments'

But it compiles and runs successfully. How can I get rid of the error in 'Error List' window? Thanks!

Comment: The only way I can recreate this *specific* problem in VS2010 is to omit the using clause from the class that is Square ... this causes the JIT compiler/intellisense to ignore the Optional() decorator on the constructor ... add the using clause and the intellisense runs fine (that is: no error message).

Comment: @Aidanapword make sure you have live semantic errors enabled. I repro'd this in VS 2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is the difference between IDE live semantic error checking and the actual compiler running.  The live semantic checking uses the C# compiler but doesn't have 100% parity with it and it can produce false positives in corner cases of the language.

To get rid of this disable live semantic checking

- Tools -> Options
- Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced
- Uncheck "Show live semantic errors"

Another way to fix this is to use the actual C# supported syntax for optional values

```
public Square(int side = 0) { }
```

Comment: Indeed: rather than using the 'interop' optional markings ... but they might be required in Dona's context (that is: is her 'Square' class IRL being called from another platform?)

Comment: @Aidanapword shouldn't be an issue because the compiler adds `Optional` from `System.Runtime.InteropServices` to the parameter automatically when using the supported optional syntax

Comment: thanks for the response. CodeDom only supports the Optional attribute syntax for optional parameter, and not the normal syntax.

Comment: @Done yeah that's a sad truth. CodeDom in general doesn't keep up with new language features.  I think your best bet then is to disable live semantic errors